# Zero-distortion map projection

Tags: real-analysis, spherical-geometry, conformal-geometry

Is it possible to take a limit of map projections (from a sphere to a plane) with ever-smaller distortion factors to get some kind of dendritic limit projection that has zero distortion everywhere? My characterization of an $\epsilon$-distortion map (defined in reverse, i.e. plane to sphere) is:

> Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to S^2$. Then $f$ is an $\epsilon$-distortion map projection iff for almost every $x\in S^2$ (except a nullset), there is a $y\in f^{-1}[x]$ such that for any $u,v\in\Bbb R^2$, $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\langle f(y+tu)-f(y),f(y+tv)-f(y)\rangle}{t^2}\in[\langle u,v\rangle(1-\epsilon),\langle u,v\rangle(1+\epsilon)].$$

Note in particular that $f$ is not required to be injective; rather every point of $S^2$ has to have *some* preimage point that is $\epsilon$-distortion. Now I can restate my question as: do $0$-distortion maps exist?

Comment: I guess by "dendritic limit" you're imagining something like [this construction of the polyconic projection](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/polyconic/)? Clearly one can create an $\epsilon$-distortion map for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ by cutting up the sphere into tiny pieces, but a map with distortion exactly $0$ feels like it should probably be forbidden by the Theorema Egregium.

Comment: @Rahul I'm not confident about what can be gleaned from the Theorema Egregium. To my mind it only shows that the domain of $f$ (restricted to its $0$-distortion subset) has no interior; obviously any little circle would have a gaussian curvature that would then invalidate the possibility of it being on the plane. The limit of the polyconic projection looks like it would have an interior, and a good amount of distortion as well. I imagine something that looks like a net for a geodesic dome, with cuts in some coherent fractal pattern, but I don't have anything consistent enough to make a limit.

Comment: I remember from general relativity the local inertial frame (here euclidean) formulated as $$y^i=\xi_p^i(x^j)$$It is a local coordinate transformation at the point p. The equation for straightening the sphere is $$g_{ij}=\frac{\partial\xi_p^k}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial\xi_p^l}{\partial x^j}\delta_{kl}$$ which transform the plane metric into the one of the sphere. The derivatives are towards x and not p, a solution is for example $$(\pm\phi\cos(p_\theta)+\theta)/\sqrt{2}$$